# How to render a same Angular component with different data? I have an Angular component which renders based on the part of the url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular13

I have a component that renders data based on the URL - '/lp/:pageId', :pageId is responsible for fetching data from the server called from `ngOnInit()`.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.apiHelper.getData(this.route.snapshot.params.pageId);
}
```

I am facing an issue when ->

- I open `/lp/apple` => this fetches data related to apple and renders properly
- But when I'm on `/lp/apple` and press the link which navigates to `/lp/banana` => only the route changes but does not fetch any data as the component is already loaded.

I tried calling the function to fetch data whenever the route changes, but that breaks some existing functionalities.

Any help regarding good Angular practice with this issue would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please share some more detail about your problem like component and routing module code.Thanks!

Comment: instead of snapshot use the subscriber on `this.route.params` instead that will trigger when you navigate between /banana and /apple

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data reactively.  Instead of fetching inside `ngOnInit`, you can define a data observable that is dependent on the route param (*since angular provides the route params as an observable on the active route*):

```js
public data$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('pageId')),
    switchMap(pageId => this.apiHelper.getData(pageId))
);

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Here the `data$` observable will emit the result of `apiHelper.getData()` whenever the route param changes.